# How to connect ElephantSQL with TypeORM?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cloud, typeorm

In documentation is only example showing connection with local database:

```
'ormconfig.json'
{
   "type": "mysql",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 3306,
   "username": "test",
   "password": "test",
   "database": "test"
}
```

I want to connect with online-based ElephantSQL and I can not find solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to connect, and here is my solution.

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "url": <URL>, 
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  "entities": ["src/entity/*.*"]
}
```

URL is the url string something like "postgres://xxxxx:5432/xxxx"